# DeMux Output - Large Pulldown Resistor Can't Pull Output Low

Tags: multiplexer

I'm using the [SN74CB3T3257](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74cb3t3257.pdf) as a demux in a circuit I'm working on.

The relevant parts of the circuit is approximately this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSXOPy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What I want is if I disconnect the external circuit, OUT reads 0.00 V, and if the external circuit is intact, it will read ~VDD. I'll use this to drive a comparator. Keeping it low power is essential as we need to run it off batteries.

When the external circuit is connected it works as expected and reads ~ 0.99*VDD. But when i disconnect the external circuit, it still reads VDD.

I tried with some lower value resistors; everything behaves as expected if R2 is in the 10 - 50 kΩ range; after I disconnect, OUT goes to 0.00 V. But as R2 gets to > 100 kΩ, OUT doesn't fall anymore.

I'm not sure if there is a parameter in the datasheet I'm missing which explains this behavior, but I couldn't find anything. I tried multiple chips to confirm it wasn't a blown chip.

Any ideas why this behavior?

**EDIT 1**: Fixed schematic and included pin numbers.

**EDIT 2**: Updated schematic to show where out leads (into comparator). Note, OUT voltage doesn't change whether or not it is connected to the comparator.

Comment: leakage current perhaps. Have you tried the resistor on the other side of the device.

Comment: As in switching the positions of R1 and R2? I can't in this case, as I need to be able to connect R1 to different circuitry in mode 2.

Comment: Can I assume 2A1 and 2A2 are really 1B1 and 1B2?  Maybe put the pin numbers because his could be a wiring problem.

Comment: I mean attaching the 1M to 2A. If the input is floating the output may actually drive high...

Comment: 2owg60 good catch, fixed.

Comment: @Trevor no dice. didn't make a difference, but thank you.

Comment: what voltage did the 1M have on it when it was on the other side?

Comment: and can you update your schematic to show what OUT goes to.

Comment: @Trevor updated schematic. V(1M Resistor) on other side = 3.396. VDD = 3.637 V, so a little lower than expected

Comment: Check the I/O leakage current spec (I_OZ). It's +/- 10 uA. More than enough to drive the pin high with a 1 Megohm load.

Comment: What is \$\overline{OE}\$ connected to?  Is Mode S?

Comment: OE  through a 10k resistor to ground. Same behavior if a direct short. Mode S = GND. If tied to VDD instead, OUT = 0.00 V.

Comment: Does that external circuit need the Vdd to work?

Comment: Thank you @ThePhoton. I didn't notice that until now. That proved to be the issue, as i swapped out for a different switch with much lower leakage current and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @ThePhoton, the critical spec here was the I/O leakage current spec (I_OZ). It was driving the output high even without an input signal when loaded with a 1 MΩ resistor.

By swapping out this demux with one which a much lower spec, everything worked as expected.